# How to Join two tables and update a column?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables as below

```
   TableA          TableB   
    ID1 ID2         ID1 ID3
    1   X           1   X
    2   NULL        2   A
    3   (NULL)      3   B
    4   (NULL)      4   C
    5   (NULL)      5   D
```

Expected Result:

```
    TableA  
   ID1  ID2
   1    X
   2    A
   3    B
   4    C
   5    D
```

My query:

```
     UPDATE TableA a LEFT JOIN TableB b  ON a.ID1 =  b.ID1
     SET a.ID2  = b.ID3 
     WHERE   a.ID2 is NULL OR  a.ID2 != b.ID3
```

But the above query is going in a loop. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Works for me: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jjCYfwGqJvnxjdk2m2Tcp9/0. But there's no need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks, I think it could be an index in issue?

Comment: If the table is large, it could be slow if `ID1` isn't indexed. Try changing to `INNER JOIN`, that's usually faster.

Comment: There's no need for the `WHERE` clause. If `a.ID2 = b.ID3`, nothing is changed by the update.

Comment: Thanks, after adding the index, the performance improved

Answer (score 0):

If your tables look exactly like the ones you have in your question then you have no need to join the tables, your resulting table is the table on the right.

```
select * 
from table b;
```

Comment: Thanks @Ereniss, the table schema is different, the mentioned columns are in both the tables.